# Sitecore Page Editor loads very slowly in production server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

In our QA environment and prod environment we have the same deployment (But different server env.). 
In PROD environment, when I log into Page editor, page editor ribbon keeps loading for 4 mins. Once it's loaded it works fine. But if I navigate to a different page again the ribbon gets loaded for 4mins.

In QA server things are fine, these deployments are identical to each other. Just wondering why it's slow in PROD env.

Any ideas?

Sitecore version 6.6

Logs says,

```
ManagedPoolThread #16 08:51:27 INFO  Job ended: AllClassifieds.Web.Extensions.Agents.WebPublisher (units processed: )
1372 08:51:54 ERROR A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (leftpane_0$hdnFSClientState="<fsclientstate></fsc...").
Exception: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
Message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (leftpane_0$hdnFSClientState="<fsclientstate></fsc...").
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.SuppressFormValidation.Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
```

This error repeats for several minutes until page editor gets loaded.

Comment: Do you see any log entries with long running operations? Link this: WARN Long running operation: getChromeData pipeline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that the performance problem is related to the validation exception you've included in your question. I think (but it's only the guess) that the reason between the speed of QA and PROD environments is the number of items in the PROD environment.

From my experience I know that sometimes there are issues with **My Items** ribbon button in **Page Editor**. It displays the number of items locked to the current user and for every ribbon reload it makes another query to get all this items.

[image]

Maybe try to remove this button (log in to **core** database and look for **/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor/Edit/My Items**) and see if this helps.

If not, I do recommend using some profiling tool like [dotTrace Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (you can download 10-day free trial) and see if it can find the problematic place.

Comment: As Maras says, the My Items button loops through all items and checks if you've locked it. There's also a web.config setting to disable this though: `WebEdit.ShowNumberOfLockedItemsOnButton`.

It might (as Maras also hints at) also be worth looking into controls which don't need to be editable. Setting that to not be editable will improve the performance a lot as well

Comment: Awesome, this is a big relief for me. Thanks heaps Maras. U saved me a day.

Comment: Any sort of indicator that shows your locked items or items in a certain workflow state is going to be bad for performance. That includes buttons like the Maras suggested you turn off as well as things like the gutter indicators to the left of the tree. You might even consider turning them off for everyone in the Core database so nobody see them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two years later and still relevant.

In Sc8 rev 4 at least.

WebEdit.ShowNumberOfLockedItemsOnButton isn't used anymore. It still exists in the code, but there are no usages of it. It doesn't affect this problem when set.

So another solution is to set amountOfLockedItems to 0 and comment out:

```
var amountOfLockedItems = context.app.canExecute("ExperienceEditor.MyItems.Count", context.currentContext);
```

In MyItems.js. Or as said, just hide/erase the button on the core database.

I guess Sitecore doesn't want to run this query on index as it would be too inaccurate for the users, but maybe they could optimize the database query a bit? We have over 9000, sorry 200000 items and it takes a whole minute to find all the locked items for the user.

Comment: There are new approaches to resolve this depending on your version of Sitecore: https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2015/12/04/14/31/549951.aspx